# Migrating Mobile App With Current Server/Client Socket Architecture

Tags: .net, networking, windows-phone-7

I've a central server serving several connections via TCP sockets. What is the easiest way to integrate a WP7 app into this architecture and thus allowing it to communicate with the server application?

Obviously connecting to the server application with a socket isn't an option since sockets aren't supported in the current version of SL for WP. The only other options I see is web services which in turn would connect to the server via sockets and WCF which is a beast I've yet to conquer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not familiar with WCF (and neither am I) then a regular web service to provide a facade over your scoket API is going to be the easiest solution to your problem.